# Tensorflow fit history is noisier than expected

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I've fitted a model and this is the plot i get with te following code:

```
hist = model.fit(
    xs, ys, epochs=300, batch_size=100, validation_split=0.1,
    callbacks=[K.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=30)]
)
plt.figure(dpi=200)
plt.plot(hist.history["loss"])
plt.plot(hist.history["val_loss"])
plt.legend(["loss", "val_loss"])
```

[image]

However, the training logs are the following:

```
...
Epoch 200/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 384ms/step - loss: 514.2175 - val_loss: 584.2152
Epoch 201/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 385ms/step - loss: 510.9814 - val_loss: 581.8872
Epoch 202/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 391ms/step - loss: 518.9771 - val_loss: 582.4727
Epoch 203/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 383ms/step - loss: 521.8132 - val_loss: 582.9196
Epoch 204/300
9/9 [==============================] - 4s 393ms/step - loss: 516.8439 - val_loss: 584.0792
Epoch 205/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 391ms/step - loss: 513.7325 - val_loss: 582.6438
Epoch 206/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 390ms/step - loss: 514.4469 - val_loss: 583.5629
Epoch 207/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 391ms/step - loss: 522.0557 - val_loss: 581.7162
Epoch 208/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 389ms/step - loss: 518.6336 - val_loss: 582.8070
Epoch 209/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 391ms/step - loss: 518.0827 - val_loss: 582.4284
Epoch 210/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 389ms/step - loss: 514.1886 - val_loss: 582.4635
Epoch 211/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 390ms/step - loss: 514.4373 - val_loss: 582.1906
Epoch 212/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 391ms/step - loss: 514.9708 - val_loss: 582.1699
Epoch 213/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 388ms/step - loss: 521.1622 - val_loss: 582.3545
Epoch 214/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 388ms/step - loss: 513.5198 - val_loss: 582.7703
Epoch 215/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 392ms/step - loss: 514.6642 - val_loss: 582.3327
Epoch 216/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 392ms/step - loss: 514.0926 - val_loss: 583.9896
Epoch 217/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 385ms/step - loss: 520.9324 - val_loss: 583.9265
Epoch 218/300
9/9 [==============================] - 4s 397ms/step - loss: 510.2536 - val_loss: 584.6587
Epoch 219/300
9/9 [==============================] - 4s 394ms/step - loss: 515.7706 - val_loss: 583.2895
Epoch 220/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 391ms/step - loss: 520.9758 - val_loss: 582.2515
Epoch 221/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 386ms/step - loss: 517.8850 - val_loss: 582.1981
Epoch 222/300
9/9 [==============================] - 4s 395ms/step - loss: 514.2051 - val_loss: 583.0013
Epoch 223/300
9/9 [==============================] - 4s 402ms/step - loss: 509.3330 - val_loss: 583.7137
Epoch 224/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 388ms/step - loss: 516.6832 - val_loss: 582.0773
Epoch 225/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 387ms/step - loss: 515.5243 - val_loss: 582.2585
Epoch 226/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 389ms/step - loss: 517.6601 - val_loss: 582.3940
Epoch 227/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 388ms/step - loss: 515.7537 - val_loss: 582.3862
Epoch 228/300
9/9 [==============================] - 4s 394ms/step - loss: 516.1107 - val_loss: 582.7234
Epoch 229/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 389ms/step - loss: 517.5703 - val_loss: 583.3829
Epoch 230/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 388ms/step - loss: 516.7491 - val_loss: 583.4712
Epoch 231/300
9/9 [==============================] - 4s 392ms/step - loss: 520.6753 - val_loss: 583.2650
Epoch 232/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 388ms/step - loss: 516.1927 - val_loss: 581.9255
Epoch 233/300
9/9 [==============================] - 4s 393ms/step - loss: 512.5476 - val_loss: 583.1275
Epoch 234/300
9/9 [==============================] - 4s 392ms/step - loss: 513.5744 - val_loss: 583.0643
Epoch 235/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 385ms/step - loss: 520.2017 - val_loss: 582.6875
Epoch 236/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 386ms/step - loss: 518.7263 - val_loss: 583.0582
Epoch 237/300
9/9 [==============================] - 3s 382ms/step - loss: 521.4882 - val_loss: 582.8977
```

Infact, if with some regex I extract the training loss, and plot it, I get the following plot:

[image]

What am I missing about `History`?...

Comment: This has been an issue in the past with tf (e.g., [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/48033)). What loss function are you using and could you try to set `model.fit(..., verbose=2)`?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/Progbar 'metrics will be averaged by the progbar before display'

Comment: @V.M instead history what is supposed to store? just the loss of the last minibatch?

Comment: @Plagon I'm using a custom `train_step`, but it's like a MSE... but to me seems that history is keeping just the last minibatch loss instead of the avg of the losses in that epoch

Comment: You need to create a "loss tracker" as described [here](https://keras.io/guides/customizing_what_happens_in_fit/#going-lowerlevel) or inherit from `tf.keras.losses.Loss`.